# NullPointer with sWakeLock in my GCMIntentService when receiving notification

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, power-management, intentservice, notificationmanager

WI have implemented push notification in my Android App.

I send notification from my server and when a notification arrived on Androide device, i get a null pointer on my sWakeLock object.

Moreover, I never called runIntentInService because i don't how to do it !

Here is the call stack :

```
10-26 13:31:55.410: E/AndroidRuntime(15351): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[71715548489]
10-26 13:31:55.410: E/AndroidRuntime(15351): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-26 13:31:55.410: E/AndroidRuntime(15351):    at com.example.android.stackwidget.GCMIntentService.onHandleIntent(GCMIntentService.java:42)
10-26 13:31:55.410: E/AndroidRuntime(15351):    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
10-26 13:31:55.410: E/AndroidRuntime(15351):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-26 13:31:55.410: E/AndroidRuntime(15351):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-26 13:31:55.410: E/AndroidRuntime(15351):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Here is also the source code of my GCMIntentService class :

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.PowerManager; 
import android.os.PowerManager.WakeLock;
import android.util.Log;

public class GCMIntentService extends IntentService {

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super(Utils.GCMSenderId);
    }

    private static PowerManager.WakeLock sWakeLock;
    private static final Object LOCK = GCMIntentService.class;
    public String regIdtoSend = "";

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        try {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION")) {
                handleRegistration(intent);
            } else if (action.equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE")) {
                handleMessage(intent);
            }
        }
        finally {
            synchronized(LOCK) {
                sWakeLock.release(); //Null pointer here on sWakeLock
            }
        }
    }

    private void handleRegistration(Intent intent) {
        String regId = intent.getStringExtra("registration_id");
        Utils.registrationId = regId;
        regIdtoSend = regId;
        new LongOperation().execute("");
        Log.e("", "registration id : "+regId);
    }

    private void handleMessage(Intent intent) {
        Utils.notiMsg = intent.getStringExtra("message");

        Context context = getApplicationContext();

        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(ns);

        int icon = R.drawable.ic_action_lab_white;
        CharSequence tickerText = Utils.notiMsg;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
        CharSequence contentTitle = "New notification";
        CharSequence contentText = Utils.notiMsg;
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);

        Utils.notificationReceived=true;

    }

    static void runIntentInService(Context context,Intent intent){
        synchronized(LOCK) {

            if (sWakeLock == null) {
                PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
                sWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "my_wakelock");
            }
        }
        sWakeLock.acquire();
        intent.setClassName(context, GCMIntentService.class.getName());
        context.startService(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to find the solution ?